# Wall and Ceiling bulging

Tags: walls, ceiling

Should  I be concerned about the lines on my walls and ceiling? The house was built in 57 and I've noticed more lines on multiple walls. See pictures attached

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Off hand I would think a bad(not nice looking) drywall mud and tape job.  It is only cosmetic and not structural.

Comment: When would I see structural? Just wondering

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a non-perfect wall finishing job. I'm going to guess it is drywall as the lines look too straight and the depth too uniform for an imperfect plaster and lathe job.

Wall coatings can hide structural problems and it is hard to say how it would be exhibited on a wall. Big cracks in exposed walls (specifically at door and window corners) are not terribly uncommon as a house settles, but given the age, that likely would have been covered up years ago.

The good news is that I don't see any water damage, you can check your foundation for large cracks, bowing, or termite dust/tubes.

If you have general concerns, you could always hire a home inspector for a few hundred dollars and they would look over everything and point out things that might need remedied/repaired sooner than later.